# Error: "Syntax error on token ";", , expected"

Tags: java, android, audio

This is the come from AndroidSnippets.com, that must help to list all music files on device.

```
    private void getallmusic() {

        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
        }; <<<<<<< Error
            ....
```

The error text is "Syntax error on token ";", , expected". What's wrong with this local variable desription?

Comment: nothing is wrong with it IMHO. Error must be somewhere else

Comment: Try to tap `CTRL+S` and clean and build your project.

Comment: You probably have a missing brace earlier in this file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error. You should back up your project or `R.java` file then go in project options and then clean the project.

Comment: Don't use messaging language here. Please edit this.

Comment: hello TG..i will change my style

Comment: thx, Mahi. after cleaning it works.